# $ \int {(1-x^2)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx} $

Tags: integration, substitution

> $ \int {(1-x^2)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx} $

My try,

substituing, $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=y$ but this doesnot work.
But, came to know it has very good answer: $xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+c$.

So, if I would substitute $xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=z$ it should work. But this is not legal way.

How to approach this integal in easier way? Any help, suggestion is highly solicited.

Comment: Integrate the second term by parts as $(x)(xe^{-x^2/2})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to notice to proceed with this integral is partially the solution in fact:

$ \int (1-x^2) e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx = \int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} - x^2e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx = \int (x)'e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} + x (e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}})' dx = \int (xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}})'dx = xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} + c $

Comment: You are a bit wrong here. I multiplied what was factored and I noticed that there is a hidden product rule if you assume $1 = (x)'$ . I would answer the same even if I didn't know the result of the integral. It is simple calculations. If you cannot see it, you should revise your calculus.

Comment: Solution is good. This one is tricky because it is NOT an obvious application of integration by parts, rather you need to recognize that the original expression is of the form $(uv)'$.

Answer (score 2):

Performing integration by parts on the second integral, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x-\int x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x \\
& =\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x+\int x d\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) \\
& =\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x+x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} d x \\
& =x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$